# Does anyone know why the items within this nested dictionary seem to be linked together?

Tags: c#, dictionary, nested, key

In the following code when I loop through the values of the float array in either the first or second dictionary within the dictionary and modify any of the values, it modifies the corresponding value in the other sub dictionary. If I for example run this code `agg_dict[report_type][0][unit_type_key][j] += 1` it's as if the computer runs `agg_dict[report_type][1][unit_category_key][j] += 1;` before it even reaches that part of the code, causing an unwanted doubling effect by the end.

This is the main function that has the bug:

```
private void add_values_to_dict(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, float[]>[]> agg_dict, float[] hour_columns, string report_type, string region, string unit_type, string unit_category)
{
    try
    {
        if (agg_dict.ContainsKey(report_type))
        {
            string unit_type_key = region + "," + unit_type;
            string unit_category_key = region + "," + unit_category;

            if (agg_dict[report_type][0].ContainsKey(unit_type_key))
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < agg_dict[report_type][0][unit_type_key].Length; j++)
                {
                    agg_dict[report_type][0][unit_type_key][j] += (float)Convert.ToDouble(hour_columns[j]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                agg_dict[report_type][0].Add(unit_type_key, hour_columns);
            }

            if (agg_dict[report_type][1].ContainsKey(unit_category_key))
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < agg_dict[report_type][1][unit_category_key].Length; j++)
                {
                    agg_dict[report_type][1][unit_category_key][j] += (float)Convert.ToDouble(hour_columns[j]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                agg_dict[report_type][1].Add(unit_category_key, hour_columns);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Dictionary<string, float[]>[] dict_array = new Dictionary<string, float[]>[2]; // 0 == unit type 1 == unit category
            dict_array[0] = new Dictionary<string, float[]>();
            dict_array[1] = new Dictionary<string, float[]>();
            dict_array[0].Add(region + "," + unit_type, hour_columns);
            float[] hour_columns_copy = hour_columns;
            dict_array[1].Add(region + "," + unit_category, hour_columns_copy);
            agg_dict.Add(report_type, dict_array);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.log(ex);
    }
}
```

And this is the function that creates the hour_columns array:

```
public void make_hours_array(string[] split_array, ref float[] hour_columns)
{
    try
    {
        hour_columns[0] = (float)Convert.ToDouble(split_array[max_capacity_index]);
        hour_columns[1] = (float)Convert.ToDouble(split_array[min_capacity_index]);

        int cnt = 2;
        for (int i = static_col_len; i < split_array.Length; i++)
        {
            //check to account for non number entries
            if (!Char.IsDigit(split_array[i][0]))
            {
                int looper = 0;
                bool has_num = false;
                foreach (char c in split_array[i])
                {
                    if (c == '-')
                    {
                        has_num = true;
                        looper++;
                        break;
                    }
                    looper++;
                }
                if (has_num)
                {
                    string finding_num = split_array[i].Trim();
                    string num = "";
                    char new_c = finding_num[looper];
                    while (!Char.IsDigit(new_c) && looper < finding_num.Length)
                    {
                        looper++;
                        new_c = finding_num[looper];
                    }
                    while (looper < finding_num.Length)
                    {
                        new_c = finding_num[looper];
                        num += new_c;
                        looper++;
                    }
                    hour_columns[cnt] = (float)Convert.ToDouble(num);
                }
                else
                {
                    hour_columns[cnt] = 0.0f;
                }
            }
            else //else copies the string array into float array
            {
                hour_columns[cnt] = (float)Convert.ToDouble(split_array[i]);
            }
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.log(ex);
    }
            
}
```

and here's both funcitons being called:

```
make_hours_array(row_split_into_array, ref hour_columns);

add_values_to_dict(agg_dict, hour_columns, report_type, region,unit_type, unit_category);
```

the one thing I know is that the float conversion in the first function is redundant. I meant to remove it prior to my last bug fixing attempt but forgot, so I left it in to remain true to what was run when I got the latest error. I figured, though redundant, it wouldn't cause this linking issue I'm having.

I was originally passing hours_column and split_array by reference and thought that was what was causing the issue. But I removed reference and the values still appear to be linked. I'm assuming it has something to do with when the sub dictionaries are created.

Comment: Honestly this code is crying out for a proper object model. `class Report { string report_type; List<float> unit_type; List<float> unit_category; }` something like that. And some Regex to parse out the strings into numbers. Why you are using floats I don't know, `decimal` is probably a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

An array is a reference type (not a value type) so the following line does not create a copy of the array - it is just another reference to the same array instance:

```cs
float[] hour_columns_copy = hour_columns;
```

Perhaps use the [Clone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.clone?view=net-7.0) method to make a shallow copy of the array.

Comment: The clone method didn't work. I tried using the copy method, and that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by separating the nested dictionary into two dictionaries and changing make_hours_array to not pass with the "ref" keyword and then initializing two different hour_colmns arrays from the start and passing each dictionary a separate array.